# Django generate many pages with a single view

Tags: python, django, django-views

my project consists of making a library with different categories of books. for each category of book I made as many views.
I would like to know if for all the existing categories I can make a single view.

---

For example here instead of three views I want only one view to manage all categories

### views.py

```py
def mathematics(request):
    mathematics_books = Books.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    total_mathematics_books = mathematics_books.count()

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(mathematics_books, 5)
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'total_mathematics_books': total_mathematics_books,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'mathematics.html',context)


def biology(request):
    biology_books = Books.objects.filter(category_id=2)
    total_biology_books = biology_books.count()

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(biology_books, 5)
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'total_biology_books': total_biology_books,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'biology.html',context)

def chemistry(request):
    chemistry_books = Books.objects.filter(category_id=3)
    total_chemistry_books = chemistry_books.count()

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(chemistry_books, 5)
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'total_chemistry_books': total_chemistry_books,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'chemistry.html',context)
```

### models.py

```py
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    biography = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Books(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Authors)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/covers/', default='pics/default-cover.jpg')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

    path('book/<int:id>/', views.detailView, name='book_detail'),
    path('all_my_books/', views.allbooks, name='allbooks'),

    #Category
    path('mathematics/', views.mathematics, name='mathematics'),
    path('chemistry/', views.chemistry, name='chemistry'),
    path('biology/', views.biology, name='biology'),
]
```

Comment: What does `urls.py` look like? And your templates (`mathematics.html`, `biology.html`, etc.)

Comment: Side note: There is no reason to make your own `total_*_books` variables. This value is already available through `page_obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only difference in your functions-view is value of `category_id`. So this should be a parameter in your URL. For example:

```
http://.../categories/1
```

Then in your `url.py`:

```
path('categories/<int:category_id>', views.category),
```

And your (single) view:

```
def category(request, category_id):
    books = Books.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    total_books = books.count()

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(books, 5)
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'total_books': total_books,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'category.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in two ways:

1. Add a parameter to your view:

   ```
   def books_by_category(request, category_id):
       books = Books.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
       total_books = books.count()

       page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

       paginator = Paginator(books, 5)
       try:
           page_obj = paginator.page(page)
       except PageNotAnInteger:
           page_obj = paginator.page(1)
       except EmptyPage:
           page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

       context = {
           'total_books': total_books,
           'page_obj': page_obj,
       }

       return render(request, 'books_by_category.html',context)
   ```

   And in `urls.py`:

   ```
   url_patterns = [
       // ...
       path('books_by_category/<int:category_id>/', views.books_by_category),
   ]
   ```
2. Use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to allow the user to pass in query parameters such as `/books/?category=5`. Follow the instructions for installation, then create a filter class:

   ```
   class BookFilter(FilterSet):
       class Meta:
           model = Books
           fields = ('category', )
   ```

   Now in your view:

   ```
   def books(request):
       queryset = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=Books.objects.all())
       # now do pagination and create context like normal
   ```